# Difference between [android] and [android-sdk] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What's the difference between the [android](/questions/tagged/android) and [android-sdk](/questions/tagged/android-sdk) tags?

Answer (score 5):

I expect that [android](/questions/tagged/android) is for general Android development questions, while [android-sdk](/questions/tagged/android-sdk) is for questions specific to the Software Development Kit.

...except it's all moot now because `android-sdk` is now a synonym for `android`.

Answer (score 0):

Android is for querying related to Android applications. But android-sdk is for tools       that are used for developing the mobile applications.

Comment: When you indent the text of your answers it puts it into "code format" mode. Please don't do that unless, of course, you're putting in some code.